# Does this block crawlers?

Tags: wordpress

submitted my wordpress site to google webmasters today, and my pages are unreachable.

I have nothing toggled in Yoast/dashboard that disallows crawlers from crawling.

In my .htaccess

is the following code , does that prevent my site for being crawled and index?

```
#BEGIN Block-Bots-ThirstyAffiliates
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Slurp|DuckDuckBot|Baiduspider|YandexBot|Sogou|Exabot|facebo|ia_archiver) [NC]
RewriteRule ^recommends/ - [L,F]
</IfModule>
#END Block-Bots-ThirstyAffiliates


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.  Using the [F] flag causes the server to return a 403 Forbidden status code to the client.  As @derek-nolan mentioned, it looks like that code is coming from the thirst affiliates plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in your htaccess suggest that a plugin called [thirsty affiliates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thirstyaffiliates/) is adding that code to block bots. If you have this plugin installed then there may be a setting within it.